# How to align a enumerate block inside "align"

Tags: equations, align, enumerate

I want to convert following segment in latex:
[image]

All the equations are written inside a "align*" block, but "enumerate" can't be placed there.
What should I do?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in, bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hlist}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
% \raggedright

\section{Матанализ от Виноградова}
\subsection{}
\textbf{Определение.} Пусть $X$ -- множство, $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ (или $\mathbb{C}$). Величина
$$
\Vert f \Vert = \sup\limits_{x\in X}{|f(x)|}
$$
называтеся \textit{равномерной} или \textit{чебышевской нормой} функции $f$.
\subsection{}
Пусть $k \in [1 : n], r \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$. Множество $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ называется \textbf{гладким $k$-мерным многообразием класса $C^{(r)}$} или \textbf{$r$-гладким $k$-мерным многообразием}, если для любого $x \in M$ существует окрестность $V_x^M$ и регулярный класса $C^{(r)}$ гомеоморфизм $\varphi : \Pi_k \to V_x^M$, такой что $\varphi(\mathbb{O}_k)=x$.

\section{Большое задание от доктора Тренча}
\subsection{}
Let $y = \int{x^2e^{-x}\sin{x}\:dx}=ue^{-x}$; then $y'=(u'-u)e^{-x}=x^2e^{-x}\sin{x}$ if $u' - u = x^2\sin{x}$. Now let

\begin{align*}
u_p\quad&=\quad (A_0 + A_1x + A_2x^2)\cos{x} + (B_0 + B_1x + B_2x^2)\sin{x};\: \mathrm{then}\\
u_p'\quad&=\quad [A_1+B_0+(2A_2+B_1)x+B_2x^2]\cos{x}\\
&\quad\quad+[B_1-A_0+(2B_2-A_1)x-A_2x^2]\sin{x};\:\mathrm{so}
\\
\\
u_p'' - u_p\quad&=\quad [-A_0+A_1+B_0-(A_1-2A_2-B_1)x-(A_2-B_2)x^2]\cos{x}\\
&\quad\quad+ [-B_0+B_1-A_0-(B_1-2B_2+A_1)x-(B_2+A_2)x^2]\sin{x}\\
&=\quad x^2\sin{x} \: \mathrm{if}\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why not just exit the align block?

Comment: @user202729 i need the list to be aligned relatively to the equations

Comment: I find the given formatting to be more confusing, not less..  I would align them with `if`, except you would need three lines instead of two.  This is a case where clarity was sacrificed for space.

Answer (score 2):

Since the conditions in your enumerated list needn't be aligned visually relative to anything in the preceding lines, I suggest you place them in a separate displaymath equation, along the lines of the code below. Note that I've also placed the connector particles -- "then", "so", "if" -- in text mode, apart from the immediate equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in, bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\section{Матанализ от Виноградова}
\subsection{}

\textbf{Определение.} Пусть $X$ -- множство, $f\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ (или $\mathbb{C}$). Величина
\[
\Vert f \Vert = \sup_{x\in X}{|f(x)|}
\]
называтеся \textit{равномерной} или \textit{чебышевской нормой} функции $f$.

\subsection{}
Пусть $k \in [1 : n]$, $r \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$. Множество $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ называется \textbf{гладким $k$-мерным многообразием класса $C^{(r)}$} или \textbf{$r$-гладким $k$-мерным многообразием}, если для любого $x \in M$ существует окрестность $V_x^M$ и регулярный класса $C^{(r)}$ гомеоморфизм $\varphi \colon \Pi_k \to V_x^M$, такой что $\varphi(\mathbb{O}_k)=x$.

\section{Большое задание от доктора Тренча}
\subsection{}
Let $y = \int x^2e^{-x}\sin{x}\,dx =ue^{-x}$.
Then $y'=(u'-u)e^{-x}=x^2e^{-x}\sin{x}$ if $u'-u = x^2\sin{x}$. 
Now let
\begin{align*}
u_p&= (A_0 + A_1x + A_2x^2)\cos{x} + (B_0 + B_1x + B_2x^2)\sin{x}. \text{ Then}\\
u_p'&= [A_1+B_0+(2A_2+B_1)x+B_2x^2]\cos{x}\\
&\qquad+[B_1-A_0+(2B_2-A_1)x-A_2x^2]\sin{x}\,.\\
\shortintertext{So}
u_p'' - u_p&= [-A_0+A_1+B_0-(A_1-2A_2-B_1)x-(A_2-B_2)x^2]\cos{x}\\
           &\qquad+ [-B_0+B_1-A_0-(B_1-2B_2+A_1)x-(B_2+A_2)x^2]\sin{x}\\
           &=x^2\sin{x}
\end{align*}
if
\[
\textrm{(i)}\quad 
   \begin{aligned} 
       -A_2+B_2 &= 0 \\
       -A_2=B_2 &= 1
   \end{aligned}
\qquad
\textrm{(ii)}\quad 
   \begin{aligned}
       -A_1+B_1+2A_2 &= 0 \\
       -A_1-B_1+2B_2 &= 0
  \end{aligned}
\qquad
\textrm{(iii)}\quad 
   \begin{aligned}
       -A_0+B_0+A_1 &= 0 \\
       -A_0-B_0+B_1 &= 0
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment: In order to align the `(i)`  element of the three-item enumerated list with the `=` symbols and center-set the material on the final line, I suggest you nest the `align*` environment in a `gather*` environment and place the final line -- the one that's to be center-set -- outside the `align*` material.

```
\begin{gather*}
\begin{align*}
u_p
  &= (A_0 + A_1x + A_2x^2)\cos{x} + (B_0 + B_1x + B_2x^2)\sin{x}. \text{ Then}\\
u_p'
  &= [A_1+B_0+(2A_2+B_1)x+B_2x^2]\cos{x}\\
  &\qquad+[B_1-A_0+(2B_2-A_1)x-A_2x^2]\sin{x}\,.\\
\shortintertext{So}
u_p'' - u_p
  &= [-A_0+A_1+B_0-(A_1-2A_2-B_1)x-(A_2-B_2)x^2]\cos{x}\\
  &\qquad+ [-B_0+B_1-A_0-(B_1-2B_2+A_1)x-(B_2+A_2)x^2]\sin{x}\\
  &=x^2\sin{x} \\
\shortintertext{if}
  &\,\textup{(i)}\quad 
   \begin{aligned} 
       -A_2+B_2 &= 0 \\
       -A_2=B_2 &= 1
   \end{aligned}\,,
   \qquad\quad
   \textup{(ii)}\quad 
   \begin{aligned}
       -A_1+B_1+2A_2 &= 0 \\
       -A_1-B_1+2B_2 &= 0
   \end{aligned}\,, 
\end{align*} \\[\jot] % end of 'align*' group
   \textup{(iii)}\quad 
   \begin{aligned}
       -A_0+B_0+A_1 &= 0 \\
       -A_0-B_0+B_1 &= 0
   \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
```

Comment: unfortunately, I need the list to have the same offset with th equations.

Comment: @ischenko - Please see the addendum I posted.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Mico's solution works great in this case, but if you really want to use an `enumerate`, you need to go out of the `align` and use `aligned` for each `\item`.  The inline environment is `{enumerate*}` and requires `\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}` package option:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate*}[label={(\roman*)}, itemjoin={\qquad}]
\item 
   $\begin{aligned} 
       -A_2+B_2 &= 0 \\
       -A_2=B_2 &= 1
   \end{aligned}$
\item 
   $\begin{aligned}
       -A_1+B_1+2A_2 &= 0 \\
       -A_1-B_1+2B_2 &= 0
  \end{aligned}$
\item 
  $ \begin{aligned}
       -A_0+B_0+A_1 &= 0 \\
       -A_0-B_0+B_1 &= 0
    \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest `aligned` inside `gather*`. Not that I find the “then” and “so” at the end of lines very attractive.

I also made some fixes.

1. `:` for functions should better be `\colon`
2. instead of unqualified `\Vert` and `|` it's better to use `\lVert...\rVert` and `\lvert...\rvert`
3. I removed all `\quad` tokens around the equals signs that make for hard reading
4. I removed all unnecessary packages; restore them, but don't load `enumitem` once with options and once without; also `hyperref` should go last
5. Insted of `\mathrm` you want `\text` for the words “then” and “so”.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in, bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\section{Матанализ от Виноградова}

\subsection{}
\textbf{Определение.} Пусть $X$ -- множство, $f\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ 
(или $\mathbb{C}$). Величина
\[
\lVert f \rVert = \sup_{x\in X}{\lvert f(x)\rvert}
\]
называтеся \textit{равномерной} или \textit{чебышевской нормой} функции $f$.

\subsection{}
Пусть $k \in [1 : n]$, $r \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$. Множество 
$M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ называется \textbf{гладким $k$-мерным многообразием 
класса $C^{(r)}$} или \textbf{$r$-гладким $k$-мерным многообразием}, если для 
любого $x \in M$ существует окрестность $V_x^M$ и регулярный класса $C^{(r)}$ 
гомеоморфизм $\varphi \colon \Pi_k \to V_x^M$, такой что $\varphi(\mathbb{O}_k)=x$.

\section{Большое задание от доктора Тренча}

\subsection{}
Let $y = \int{x^2e^{-x}\sin{x}\,dx}=ue^{-x}$; then 
$y'=(u'-u)e^{-x}=x^2e^{-x}\sin{x}$ if $u' - u = x^2\sin{x}$. Now let
\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
u_p         &= (A_0 + A_1x + A_2x^2)\cos{x} + (B_0 + B_1x + B_2x^2)\sin{x};\quad\text{then}
\\[1ex]
u_p'        &= [A_1+B_0+(2A_2+B_1)x+B_2x^2]\cos{x}\\
            &\qquad+[B_1-A_0+(2B_2-A_1)x-A_2x^2]\sin{x};\quad\text{so}
\\[1ex]
u_p'' - u_p &= [-A_0+A_1+B_0-(A_1-2A_2-B_1)x-(A_2-B_2)x^2]\cos{x}\\
            &\qquad+ [-B_0+B_1-A_0-(B_1-2B_2+A_1)x-(B_2+A_2)x^2]\sin{x}\\
            &= x^2\sin{x} \quad \text{if}
\end{aligned}
\\[1ex]
\textup{(i)}\quad
\begin{aligned} -A_2+B_2 &= 0 \\ -A_2-B_2 &= 1 \end{aligned}
\qquad\qquad
\textup{(ii)}\quad
\begin{aligned} -A_1+B_1+2A_2 &= 0 \\ -A_1-B_1+2B_2 &= 1 \end{aligned} \\
\textup{(iii)}\quad
\begin{aligned} -A_0+B_0+A_1 &= 0 \\ -A_0-B_0+B_1 &= 1 \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot.